# How to create a folder from file name and moved it in PHP?

Tags: php, file, directory

Suppose I had got the file in my File directory containing 6 files:

```
File|-> Pic_Pic1.jpg
    |-> Pic_Pic2.jpg
    |-> Pic_Pic3.jpg
    |-> Img_Img1.jpg
    |-> Img_Img2.jpg
    |-> Img_Img3.jpg
```

Here FolderName_FileName.jpg

Now i want the PHP script that create Folder from the file name and move it on its correct location..

That is i want like

```
File|-> Pic|-> Pic_Pic1.jpg
    |      |-> Pic_Pic2.jpg
    |      |-> Pic_Pic3.jpg
    |-> Img|-> Img_Img1.jpg
           |-> Img_Img2.jpg
           |-> Img_Img3.jpg




<?php
    define('START_DIR', 'rec');
    define('DEST_DIR', 'rename');
    define('SEPARATOR', '\\');

    function firstStage() {
        $d = dir(START_DIR);
        while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
            if($entry != '.' && $entry != '..')
                secondStage($entry);
        }
        $d->close();
    }

    function secondStage($prefix) {
        $d = dir(START_DIR . SEPARATOR . $prefix);
        while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
            if($entry != '.' && $entry != '..')
                rename(START_DIR . SEPARATOR . $prefix . SEPARATOR . $entry, DEST_DIR . SEPARATOR . $prefix . '_' . $entry);
        }
        $d->close();
    }

    firstStage();
?>
```

Comment: Also share the code which you have tried.

Comment: You are expected to **try to write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Look up php functions of mkdir and copy

Comment: @SahilGulati ,@Jay Blanchard...

Comment: @SahilGulati ,@Jay Blanchard..but the code is reverse of that

Comment: don't do `define('SEPARATOR', '\\');` instead use the predefined global `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like this.

```
<?php
define('START_DIR', 'rec');

foreach (glob(START_DIR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '/*.jpg') as $file) {
    list(,$filename) = explode('/', $file);
    list($destination, ) = explode('_', $filename);
    $newdir = START_DIR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$destination;
    if(!@mkdir($newdir) && !is_dir($newdir) ) {
        throw new Exception('Cannot create new directory', 0755);
    }
    rename($file, $newdir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename);
}
?>
```